# Persisting my first entity using Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jpa

Trying to get my head around `Java EE` (ORM/Entities/Annotations/EJB/Servlets etc.). So I've created a very simple webpage where you can enter user information and send it to the server. I'm using `Apache Tomcat 8.0` as webbserver application and here is all the relevant parts of the application files and content that is needed to persist an entity:

http://pastebin.com/fwfbnYpU

The application gives me the error on line 99 saying:

```
08-Apr-2014 16:18:10.329 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-93] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [indexServlet] in context with path [/JavaEENackademin] threw exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
```

What am I doing wrong? The database exist with the correct named table and columnnames. But then again that is not the problem here maybe it will become a problem after I fix this problem :)

Comment: Please post your code directly in the question.

Comment: I think the main pain point is that you're trying to use a servlet container like tomcat to learn JavaEE (which contains much more than what tomcat is able to do). You might want to look into [tomee](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html) for additional components on top of Tomcat.

Comment: You should post the relevant parts of the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised you are able to deploy the code in your pastebin. Especially:

```
@WebServlet(name = "indexServlet", urlPatterns = {"/indexServlet"})
public class indexServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    LoginValidation validation;
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "JavaEENackademinPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    //... offending line 99 calls: em.persist()
}
```

Neither `PersistenceContext` nor `Inject` are part of the servlet spec, so you probably added additional jars to your installation.

But you configured your `persistence.xml` to use JTA transactions which are barely supported in a servlet environment, probably resulting in tomcat ignoring the `@PersistenceContext` annotation altogether and leaving `em == null` (the default value).

I've found [this link](http://solecjj.wikispaces.com/JTA+with+Tomcat+7) describing an integration but it looks complicated, requires editing internal xml files and then goes on to use Spring. Likely every part of that is overkill for a beginner.

I suggest you start fresh with a copy of [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html) which already does all the wiring to get you a fully fledged application server that supports CDI (`@Inject`) and JPA (`@PersistenceContext`) out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

One issue with your code is that you should not inject `EntityManager`s into servlets. Servlets are usually singletons, so all servlets would use the same `EntityManager`. You should inject an `EntityManagerFactory` instead and get your `EntityManager`s from it. You also have to take care of transactions. Not sure if this has caused your issues, but something that should be fixed.